# Multi-instruction equivalent to leal 4(%esp), %ecx?

Tags: assembly, x86

i was curious if this is proper way to rewrite some of my asm instructions:
(without affecting functionality)

would:

```
leal  4(%esp), %ecx
```

be same as:

```
leal %esp, %ebx
addl $4, $ebx
leal %ebx, %ecx
```

also, would:

```
movl -4/%ebp), %ecx
```

be same as:

```
movl %ebp, %ebx
subl $4, %ebx
movl (%ebx), %exc
```

Register **%ebx** has not been used by assembler, so im sure i can introduce (use) it for these modifications.
Im also trying to figure out how to rewrite `pushl -4( %ecx)` in similar way as two examples above

Comment: so, one is a single instruction, the other is 3 instructions. I wouldn't call this "the same".

Comment: yes, i understand, i meant would this be proper way to rewrite them this without changing purpose (functionality) of my code... For example `a = b + (c * d)` , rewrite to `f = c * d` and `a = b + f`

Comment: alright, but why? Just asking to rule out an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), after all, this would take more memory, cycles and registers .. ;)

Comment: @Felix Palmen  i understand your questions, this is a task i should do and point of it is: change indirect complex addressing modes (such as: inexed mode, based mode, scaled factor and based factor) to **simple indirect addresing modes**, without changing functionality of program.. Im not trying to find someone to solve it for me, just to check if im doing it correctly

Comment: well, sorry, I just wanted to make sure there's nothing missing, so you won't get answers that don't really help in the end :) To me, this code looks ok, but I'm no expert in x86 assembly -- better wait for some answer! I only looked at this question because you initially tagged it C -- not really related ...

Comment: `leal %esp, %ebx` is invalid. It's either `leal (%esp), %ebx` or just `mov %esp, %ebx`. Also it makes no sense to involve `ebx` you can do it in 2 steps as `mov %esp, %ecx; add $4, %ecx`.

Comment: I don't think `leal %esp, %ebx` is valid syntax and would compile. But why don't you simply try them in debugger? Write + compile (fix syntax) + step over in debugger (with test values which will unambiguously report success/failure in case the new variant is not equal). Done (or ask on SO with particular debug values in question, if you can't get grasp on the results of such try). This is very near the http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ case...

Comment: *Register %ebx has not been used by assembler, so im sure i can introduce (use) it for these modifications.* No, in most calling conventions, functions need to preserve their caller's EBX.  [Why does IA-32 have a non-intuitive caller and callee register saving convention?](//stackoverflow.com/q/8335582).  Using it as a scratch register could make the program crash after your function returns.  (This doesn't apply if you have no caller, i.e.  at the `_start` entry point, or you use `sys_exit` instead of returning.)